# SQL Injection using Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-injection

I have the following problem: I need a dynamic create statement, depending on what attributes my object has.

its following object:

```
class Table:

    columns = []

    def __init__(self, name, columns):
        self.columns = columns
        self.name = name

    def columnsNumber(self) -> int:
        return self.columns.__len__()
```

this is what the insert looks like:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tableOverview (tableName, columns, datum) VALUES(%s, %s, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"
            val = (table.name, table.columns.__len__())
            await cursor.execute(sql, (val))


for x in table.columns:
        sql = "ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE " % (table.name,x)
        await cursor.execute(sql)
```

now I don't know, how to prevent a SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

For the `ALTER TABLE` statements you can quote the identifier names with backticks as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).

```py
for x in table.columns:
    sql = "ALTER TABLE `%s` ADD COLUMN `%s` VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE " % (table.name,x)
    await cursor.execute(sql)
```

In the insert statement, the code is already correctly using parameter substitution to ensure the inserted values are correctly quoted.

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO tableOverview (tableName, columns, datum) VALUES(%s, %s, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);" 
val = (table.name, table.columns.len()) 
await cursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Comment: A point of style: we generally don't call `__len__()` directly in python, or create methods named `len`: if a class needs to provide a way to get its length define `__len__()` but call it through `len(obj)`, not `obj.__len__()`.